# Top user record keeping

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

I plan to apply to college soon and might want to mention that [I](https://superuser.com/users/81403/wizlog) got to be in the [top .59%](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/3/quarter/superuser/2011-10-01/81403#81403) of all users on superuser for this quarter.

Is there any way for them to verify, or for me to prove it to them?

How else should I tag this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to the **[Reputation Leagues](http://stackexchange.com/leagues)**, and provide a link to them from there.

Here is the link that goes to your position on the top users of all time:

> http://stackexchange.com/leagues/3/alltime/superuser/2008-08-01/81403?sort=reputationchange#81403

Daniel Beck also noted you can view the current quarter:

> http://stackexchange.com/leagues/3/quarter/superuser/2011-10-01/81403?sort=reputationchange#81403